# Casting an int into a float results in an incorrect value (not the usual decimal rounding error though)

Tags: c, arduino

For some reason I am getting some very unexpected results when converting an integer in to a float (using c(-ish) on Arduino).
In the past I have had problems with memory on the arduino so that may be either a helpful troubleshooting hint or a red herring.... you're pick.

Anyways, here is my code (only the relevant parts), and the value that is given is "6/8" which should result in meterValue = 0.75:

My function:

```
int getIntegerFromFileStream(File f, char* previewedChar) {
    int num = 0;
    while (48 <= *previewedChar && *previewedChar <= 57) {
        // Ascii range 48-57 represents digits 0-9
        num = (num*10) + atoi(previewedChar);
        *previewedChar = f.read();
    }
    Serial.print(F("Found integer: "));
    Serial.println(num);
}
```

Main code:

```
[.... rest of my code ....]    
// Get the value for the meter from the fractional form (ex: 4/4 or 6/8)    
meterValue = (float)getIntegerFromFileStream(file, &inputChar);    
Serial.print(F("New meter value: "));    
Serial.println(meterValue);    
if (inputChar == '/') {    
    inputChar = file.read(); // move past the '/'    
    meterValue /= (float)getIntegerFromFileStream(file, &inputChar);    
    Serial.print(F("New meter value: "));    
    Serial.println(meterValue);    
}    
[.... rest of my code ....]
```

And here is the output from the above code:

> Found integer: 6
>   New meter value: 3.00
>   Found integer: 8
>   New meter value: 1.00
>   New meter value: 1.00

As you can see from the output, the integer itself is being parsed correctly, but once it leaves the function and is casted to a float, its value changes (and not in the usual float-decimal-error way).
Any tips would be appreciated!

Edit:

Found my newb mistake:  i don't have a return value for my getInt function, so it was resulting in undefined behaviour.
Turns out that, by default, Arduino does not give warnings during compilation unless you specifically go in to Preferences and turn on 'verbose' output for compilation.  Once that was set I was able to see these kinds of warnings.
(this is only edited in for now because I'm too new to stackoverflow to answer my own question yet, i'll do so once my time limit is up)

Comment: What is the type of `meterValue`?

Comment: the meterValue was set to float.  but please see my recent edit, I have found my mistake thankfully x)

Comment: Great you found it. I spotted it and was about to comment.

Comment: Minor: suggest `while ('0' <= *previewedChar && *previewedChar <= '9')`.

Comment: +1 for the tip about turning on verbose output. That is useful information even if the problem is a simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my newb mistake:  i don't have a return value for my getInt function, so it was resulting in undefined behaviour.
Turns out that, by default, Arduino does not give warnings during compilation unless you specifically go in to Preferences and turn on 'verbose' output for compilation.  Once that was set I was able to see these kinds of warnings.